# two fieldsets with display inline aligning on bottom

Tags: html, css

I have two fieldsets in one form who are displayed inline. They appear next to each other, but they are aligned at the bottom rather than at the top. It looks like this:

[image]

This is the html:

```
<form action='php/register.php' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <label for='txtfirstName'>Voornaam*</label>
        <input id='txtfirstName'  name='firstname' type='text' value='$firstname'>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for='txtfirstName'>Voornaam*</label>
        <input id='txtfirstName'  name='firstname' type='text' value='$firstname'>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the css:

```
fieldset {
    display:inline;
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the CSS property `vertical-align: top` works just fine.

Comment: FYI: Just been testing some fieldsets in various browsers and it appears that Firefox bottom aligns by default, where Chrome, Opera (Chrome), Safari all align top by default, which can be somewhat confusing when you think your layout is all working nicely, until it suddenly isn't.